# Code failing to run the second time, but runs after _pycache_ folder is deleted?

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting an overflow error immediately after running the exact same code for the second time (the first run works as expected). However, deleting the associated *pycache* folder seems to reset everything and I can run the code once more.

What is even more confusing is that I do not encounter this problem at all when running the exact same code on a different computer. The only difference is that one computer is running on Windows 7, the other on Windows 10. I'm also not sure if one is running Idle 3.6 vs. 3.7, though I'm not sure if this is relevant.

Edit:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Projects\New folder\double_pendulum.py", line 42
a = (-1/2)*(f1(th1,th2,p1,p2)*f2(th1,th2,p1,p2)*m.sin(th1-th2)+3*g*m.sin(th1))
```

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

Comment: Without seeing any code I doubt we can have any idea where the error comes from.  You should at least include the relevant snippets shown by the traceback.

Comment: I don't know what code to include as the script works perfectly on my other computer. I've added the error but not sure of its relevance to the problem. I was hoping it may be an issue that others have encountered relating to this particular version of python.

Comment: If the version of IDLE were the problem, it should not happen when you run it from the commandline. Worth trying that out.  
Also, do both computers have the same python version?

Comment: The error is not enough. You should add your code too.

Comment: Please try to not just show the code, but try to make a program that behaves the same with as few code as you manage ([MCVE])

Comment: Aha, it's a warning, not an error!  The next step is to split out your super-complicated one-liner into separate steps to isolate the error (i.e. to find out which input variable is causing the problem.

Comment: Creating a program that behaves the same has been a struggle, and I haven't made any progress towards finding out what is causing the problem on this computer. I appreciate the replies and I will either update this thread/create a new one depending on usual protocol when I'm back from holiday, hopefully with a working example. Would posting a link to a github repository be allowed for the time being?